# overflow: auto not working correctly with Facebook Like Comment Flyout

Tags: facebook-like, overflow

To save my time trying to explain it, here's a 'working' example:

http://jsfiddle.net/z56Dt/19/

When you click the 'Slide' button, the div height expands as it should. But when you click the Like button, it gets the scrollbar. I can't even add an onclick event to the fb-like DIV. Any ideas?

Comment: Really, no one has any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had/have the same problem... with overflow set to auto it adds scrollbars. With overflow set to visible it works fine... my problem is I need the parent div to be set to overflow:auto to make the layout look ok.